# Using a button to link a website

Tags: android, file, button, hyperlink, download

I want users to click on a button, which then displays a website on my app, NOT ON A BROWSER, just on a new xml. Also, this website will have files, which I want them to be able to view on the app and they don't have to download them? How can i do this,  please help!

Comment: Use webview. But the file thing.. that depends on what type of files you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an activity with a webview, You can start it by calling `startActivity`:

```
Intent activityWithWebView = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("url", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then, in the next activity, you can get the url and feed the webview:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String url = b.getString("url");
```